# possible to run PCA in R assuming columns are samples and rows are variables?

Tags: r, pca

I have a file with 500K variables (DNA changes) and 60K samples.

I am finding reading "wide" files typically takes longer that "long" files, so it would be better is I could read in my data with samples as columns

as I understand it `prcomp` assumes samples are rows and variables are columns, but is there a way to make it assume samples are columns and variables are rows?

Comment: You could try transposing with `t()` or `data.table::transpose()`, but I doubt that would be more efficient than importing the data in wide format from the get-go.

Comment: Have you looked into the various strategies for speeding up file-reading?